# pass values from page to http handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have a .net c# web forms in my web application. I do some processing in the code behind of this page.

Within the mark up of this page, I have a http handler referenced, which outputs a response type of text/javascript, included in the markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="handler.axd"></script>
```

I want to pass from my page to the http handler some values. I do not want to pass it via query string and session is not available to me.

Any ideas or tips as to how I can pass data/variable values from my page to the http handler?

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to pass it via query string and session is not available to me

[Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx)? In your main page set a cookie, and in the handler read the value of the cookie.

If this is not an option for you how about [Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx)? In your main page generate an unique GUID and store the value you would like to pass to the handler into the application state. Then pass the GUID to the handler as request parameter. In the handler use the GUID to fetch the value from application state.

If application state is not an option for you how about database state (or some other persistent storage mechanism on server)?

If all those are not an options for you describe your scenario in more details as I am afraid that you could quickly run out of options :-)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to introduce another cookie in the site. I already have several cookies in the site.

Comment: @amateur, having multiple cookies is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to use qs variables, but you could do the following.  Create a unique key on page load, store your variables in Application Cache by that key, and stick that key as a querystring variable on you script reference, then access that information from Application Cache again.  This is assuming that you're concerned about security or data size as the reason for now sticking directly in the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the HttpContext.Items collection?

Comment: Would it not be 2 separate requests therefore the HttpContext.Items would not be shared?